# How to create remember me action using laravel auth

Tags: laravel-4

i have a checkbox with my login form , which will remember user when checked . I am using following code but it doesnot works for me :

VIEW :

```
 @extends('layouts.main') 
@section('title') Dashboard 
@stop
@section('content')
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'users/signin', 'class'=>'form-signin')) }}
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Login</h2>

    {{ Form::text('email', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Email Address')) }}
    {{ Form::password('password', array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Password')) }}
    {{ Form::checkbox('remember_me','false',false,array('class'=>'input-block-level')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class'=>'btn btn-large btn-primary btn-block'))}}
{{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

CONTROLLER :

```
public function postSignin() {
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password'),'active' => 1),Input::has('remember_me'))) {
        return Redirect::to('users/dashboard')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('users/login')
        ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
        ->withInput();
    }
}
```

Please help me out on this , This function does not remembers user .
If you have some better code then please tell me that .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to remember a user pass the third parameter `true`

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true))
{
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

**Your code:**

```
public function postSignin() {

    $rememberMe = false;

    if(Input::has('remember_me')) {
       $rememberMe = true;
    } 

   if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=> Input::get('email'), 'password'=> Input::get('password') ), $rememberMe )) {
      return Redirect::to('users/dashboard')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
} else {
    return Redirect::to('users/login')
    ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
    ->withInput();
}
}
```

Comment: There is an error when i login using code you wrote above :    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = ? and `active` = ? and `0` = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'vikas@sohyper.com', 1 => 1, 2 => true, ))